# Where can I read the text on the Jelly Belly brand Harry Potter chocolate frogs?

Tags: harry-potter, merchandise

Jelly Belly sells Harry Potter chocolate frogs. These come with collectible cards, just like the Famous Witches and Wizards Cards from the books and films.

> Each one comes with new collectible cards featuring legendary wizards and witches from the books, and films, bringing some of the most popular Wizarding World's characters to life.
>
> <sub>[Product info on *Jelly Belly* website](https://www.jellybelly.com/harry-potter-chocolate-frogs/c/436)</sub>

Are these cards available online somewhere?

Comment: Most candy chocolate frog cards seem to a mixture of paraphrases from Rowling's card list and basic bios from the books/movies. Occasionally (like the original Hasbro candies) they add in their own fluff as well.

Comment: While I do not think this is too broad, the current answers seem to be pulling from three or four different sets of cards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There are 16 Cards

From the [Jelly Belly](https://www.jellybelly.co.uk/harry-potter-milk-chocolate-frog-15g) set, the list of cards are:

Gilderoy Lockhart
Madam Pince
The Potter Family
Rubeus Hagrid
Voldemort
Severus Snape
Myron Wagtail & Heathcote Barbary
Filius Flitwick
Pomona Sprout
Madam Rolanda Hooch
Donaghan Tremlett & Myron Wagtail
Quirinus Quirrell
Mr. Ollivander
Albus Dumbledore
Minerva McGonagall
Orsino Thurston & Mryon Wagtail

The other sides of the cards have holographic images, but these are the back-sides:

**Here is Dumbledore, Sprout, Snape, Pince and Lockhart**

[image]

**McGonagall**

[image]

**Hagrid**

[image]

**Quirell**

[image]

**Whoops, forgot Flitwick**

[image]

**And Hooch**

[image]

**And Ollivander**

[image]

**Voldemort**

[image]

**Barbary, Wagtail, Tremlett and Thurston**

[image]
[image]

**And lastly, the rare Potter Family**

[image]

### Further Proof

The front and back of the Hagrid card is taken by the same person and a different photo shows the fronts of the cards with the Chocolate Frog wrapper and candy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do they say #X/12 if there are 16?

Comment: @ibid Because I'm silly and forgot to upload 3 of the photos. Done.

Comment: The first twelve cards you show seem to be very clearly from a twelve card set (see the bottom-right corner) of cards written based on book info. The next three don't have numbers and are lifted directly from the cards JKR wrote for the EA games. The last one is a different color and contains a passage excerpted from the book. Do you have any evidence that *these* are the JellyBelly cards and not just cards from three other sets?

Comment: @ibid Yes, besides the designs matching the chocolate frog wrapper, if you look at the photo splaying out the two Wagtail cards, you can see the red family card behind it. If you look on ebay, people are showing both sides of the card and the packaging. I didn't want to post an ebay link as reference because those  can disappear. The card set probably got extended after the first edition so people would be incentivized to buy more, which is why they stopped numbering the new ones.

Comment: Why does Myron Wagtail appear three times on three separate cards?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Not sure, just the way that Jelly Belly decided to do it I guess.

Answer (score 9):

I found some pictures on eBay. Unfortunately, I haven't found them all as there are [16 in the Jelly Belly set total](https://www.jellybelly.co.uk/harry-potter-milk-chocolate-frog-15g). Click each image to enlarge. (I'll see about transcribing them when I have time.)

[Dumbledore](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2017-JELLY-BELLY-chocolate-frog-wizard-card-ALBUS-DUMBLEDORE-/152948711436):

[image]

[Slytherin](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HARRY-POTTER-Chocolate-Frog-Founder-Card-SALAZAR-SLYTHERIN-New-2018-Jelly-Belly-/352316910912):

[image]

[Ravenclaw](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HARRY-POTTER-Chocolate-Frog-Founder-Card-ROWENA-RAVENCLAW-New-2018-Jelly-Belly/352316911055):

[image]

[Hufflepuff](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HARRY-POTTER-Chocolate-Frog-Founder-Card-HELGA-HUFFLEPUFF-New-2018-Jelly-Belly/352316910750):

[image]

[Godric Gryffindor](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2017-JELLY-BELLY-chocolate-frog-wizard-card-GODRIC-GRYFFINDOR-/112854317401):

[image]

---

As a bonus, here are some from the other set (not Jelly Belly as far as I know). Note the similarities between some of the blurbs:

[Gryffindor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Godric-Gryffindor-Harry-Potter-Chocolate-Frog-Card/232708019170):

[image: Gryffindor]

[Bertie Bott](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Bertie-Bott-Chocolate-Frog-Card-Harry-Potter-RARE-Card-only-/222908564385):

[image: Bott]

[Slytherin](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Salazar-Slytherin-Chocolate-Frog-Card-from-the-Wizarding-World-of-Harry-Potter/253524541043):

[image]

[Lockhart](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Gilderoy-Lockhart-Chocolate-frog-card-Harry-Potter-WILL-MEET-OR-BEAT-COMPETITORS-/142736450169):

[image]

[Hengist of Woodcroft](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HENGIST-OF-WOODCROFT-Harry-Potter-Chocolate-Frog-Card-EXTREMELY-RARE/323161602914):

[image]

[Rock Band](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-Chocolate-Frogs-Trading-Cards-3-Card-Rock-Band-Short-Print-Set/253495313547):

[image]

[Hooch, Sprout Flitwick](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Harry-Potter-Chocolate-frog-cards-series-4-Hooch-Pomona-Sprout-Flitwick/273137094597):

[image]